# How to bold / unbold tablix text with an expression?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have an expression in a textbox of a tablix control:

```
="Rectification: " + Fields!MoreInfo.Value
```

What I would like to do is have the word 'Rectification:' in bold and the rest of the text unbolded. Unfortunately I've no idea how to do this.

I've tried the following (as per a suggestion from Google):

```
="<b>Rectification:</b> " + Fields!MoreInfo.Value
```

However this shows the  tags in their literal form. It also appears that expressions on the bold context apply to the entire textbox and cannot apply to only some parts of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use placeholders to accomplish this.

[Here's](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/10/31/using-different-formats-within-a-single-textbox-in-ssrs.html) an excellent tutorial.